# Zero set of non-constant polynomial , in more than one variable, over uncountable algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, model-theory

Let $n>1$, $K$ be an uncountable algebraically closed field and $f(X_1,...,X_n)\in K[X_1,...,X_n] $ be  a non-constant polynomial. Then it is known that $Z(f):=\{\bar a \in K^n : f(\bar a)=0\}$ is infinite. My question is, can $Z(f)$ be countable ?

If $K=\mathbb C$, it is known that $Z(f)$ contains a connected (in the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb C^n$) subset (corresponding to an irreducible factor of $f$), hence is always uncountable.

Comment: if you vary $n-1$ of the coordinates, you get an uncountable family of polynomials in the last coordinate, all of the same degree. probably no two are scalar multiples of eachother except in some degenerate cases.... just some thoughts that may have already occured to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons and tons of ways to prove this.  Here's probably the lowest-tech way.

Since $f$ is nonconstant, some variable appears in $f$; suppose without loss of generality that it is $X_1$.  Consider $f$ as a polynomial in $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$ with coefficients in $K[X_n]$.  Since $X_1$ appears in $f$, this polynomial with coefficients in $K[X_n]$ is nonconstant.  For all but finitely many values of $a\in K$, then, $f(X_1,\dots,X_{n-1},a)$ will still be nonconstant (since $a$ just needs to not be a simultaneous root of all the coefficients besides the constant term).   Since such a nonconstant polynomial has a root, this gives uncountably many roots of $f$.

(Or, if you don't know that a nonconstant polynomial has a root, you can continue this argument by induction on $n$ to prove it.)